# Perform User Authentication if email provided exists in the database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, basic-authentication

In Laravel, is it possible to do a sign-in base on user email only - no password needed.

---

**I'ved tried**

```
public function postSignIn(){

      $validator = Validator::make(Input::only('email') , array(
        'email' => 'required',
      ));

      if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('/')->with('error', 'Please fill out your information ')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
      }

      $email = strtolower(Input::get('email'));

      $auth = Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email ));

      if ($auth) {
        return Redirect::to('/dashboard')->with('success', 'Hi '. Auth::user()->name .'! You have been successfully logged in.');
      }

      else {
        return Redirect::to('/')->with('error', 'Username/Password Wrong')
          ->with('username', $username)
          ->withErrors($validator);
      }
```

---

I keep getting : `Undefined index: password`

Do I need to modify the any kind of Auth driver for this to work ?

Any hints/ suggestions on this will be much appreciated !

Comment: Setting one random and same password for all users when registering and supplying it with email for authentication is one of the quick ways to do it.

Comment: Smart ! I should have think of that. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
public function postSignIn(){

      $validator = Validator::make(Input::only('email') , array(
        'email' => 'required',
      ));

      if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('/')->with('error', 'Please fill out your information ')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
      }

      $email = strtolower(Input::get('email'));

      try{
          $user = User::where('email', $email)->firstOrFail();
          Auth::login($user);

          return Redirect::to('/dashboard')->with('success', 'Hi '. Auth::user()->name .'! You have been successfully logged in.');
      }
      catch(ModelNotFoundException $exception){
          return Redirect::to('/')->with('error', 'Username/Password Wrong')
            ->with('username', $username)
            ->withErrors($validator);

      }
}
```

You can check more info in [here](http://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication#remembering-users) on how to manually login your users (you will have to scroll down a little bit)

Comment: @ihue btw you might have to change the catch part, I noticed that you don't have the $username variable defined before

Comment: You catch suggestion doesn't seem to work. It log me in when I enter an existing email. But when there isn't , I got `NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 46:
No query results for model [App\User].`

Comment: Did you import the Exception? You have to import it on the beginning of your PHP class `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;`

Comment: I haven't doing it now. Testing it now. Thanks.

Comment: Work perfectly ! You saved my life mate ! :)

Comment: Glad I could help out!  Cheers